# how to call a matrix variable into a method

Tags: java, matrix, methods, serversocket

i'm learning about socket programming but i have a little problem with this matrix. I know that is a stupid problem but i don't know how to resolve it

```
void data(){
    String[][] serv = { {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"} };
    System.out.println(server [1] [0]);
}

void process(String[][] serv){
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Processing...\n");
    try{
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {

            System.out.println(serv [i] [0]);
            if (request.equals(serv [i] [0])) {
                response = serv [i] [1];
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Non trovato");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    final int port = 6000;
    ServerSocket listenSock = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Server avviato. In ascolto su: " + listenSock.getLocalPort() + "\n");
    while(true){
        Socket socket = listenSock.accept();
        System.out.println("Stabilita connessione con: "+socket.getPort()+"\n");
        TCPServer server = new TCPServer(socket);
        server.getRequest();
        server.data();
        server.process();
        server.sendResponse();
        server.close();     
    }
}
```

when i compile javac give me this message

`TCPServer.java:88: error: method process in class TCPServer cannot be applied to given types;
            server.process();
                  ^
  required: String[][]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

any ideas to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your array must be an instance variable and not local to the data() method :

```
String[][] serv;
void data(){
    serv = { {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"} };
    System.out.println(server [1] [0]);
}
```

Then you can use it directly in the `process` method without passing anything :

```
void process() {
   ...
```

Your main method can remain unchanged.

Another alternative is to return the array from the `data()` method and pass it to the `process()` method :

```
String[][] data(){
    String[][] serv = { {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"}, {"url", "url ip"} };
    System.out.println(serv [1] [0]);
    return serv;
}
```

And in your main method :

```
    server.process(server.data());
```

In this solution you don't change anything in the `process()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `server.process()` method takes a double-dimension array of `String`.

In your `main` method, you invoke it without arguments, hence the error.